# A Book about the Bohr-Einstein debate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, resource-recommendations, history

A book about the [Bohr-Einstein debate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Einstein_debates)?

Is there any book that details the correspondence between the two? The only books I could find are popular science books, I wonder if there is a book that lists the correspondence in a more 'raw' form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [essay](http://www.math.kun.nl/~landsman/EBpubl.pdf) by N.P. Landsman: "When champions meet: Rethinking the Bohr–Einstein debate." Studies In History and Philosophy of Science Part B: Studies In History and Philosophy of Modern Physics 37.1 (2006): 212-242” contains an extensive bibliography on the debate.

In particular the main references containing or discussing the letters are listed in footnote 1 on page 213.